# Dynamically append function to AppSync Pipeline Resolver via CloudFormation

Tags: amazon-web-services, aws-cloudformation, pipeline, aws-appsync, resolver

I am currently developing an AppSync based API in a domain driven manner, so we need to put a function to an already created Pipeline Resolver. Does anybody know if there is there any chance doing this via CloudFormation without using a custom resource?

Thanks in advance, Sven

Comment: I haven't tried this but you should be able to add the function to the [`PipelineResolverConfig`](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/AWSCloudFormation/latest/UserGuide/aws-properties-appsync-resolver-pipelineconfig.html) and CloudFormation should handle the update.

Answer (score 0):

**Terraform can do this neatly** if you can build this [pull request](https://github.com/terraform-providers/terraform-provider-aws/pull/8502) yourself or vote in [this issue](https://github.com/terraform-providers/terraform-provider-aws/issues/8127) to get it merged into a public release.

The new syntax is described [here](https://github.com/terraform-providers/terraform-provider-aws/blob/bb4fb2a41c1df06d61925c3724808e9b009221fc/website/docs/r/appsync_function.html.markdown).

The build process is actually quite simple. It took me about 30 min end-to-end.

1. Install GoLang.
2. Clone the repo with the changes and [sync it](https://help.github.com/en/articles/syncing-a-fork) with the main (upstream) repo.
3. Make sure you cloned it into `go\src\github.com\terraform-providers\terraform-provider-aws` folder.
4. Run `go build` from `go\src\github.com\terraform-providers\terraform-provider-aws`
5. Replace `.terraform\plugins\...\terraform-provider-aws-*` executable with the one you compiled.
6. Run `terraform init`
7. Test by trying to import a function `terraform import aws_appsync_function.example xxxxx-yyyyy`

**I hope the pull request gets merged by the time you read this.**